# Arrangements of the word HULLABALOO

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Three problems below with my attempt solutions:

> 1) How many ways (ordered selections) can the letters of the word HULLABALOO be arranged?

$$\frac{10!}{3!2!2!}$$

> 2) How many distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word HULLABALOO begin with the letter U and end with the letter L?

I took these to be accepted positions, and thus the letters are reduced to HLLABAOO

$$\frac{8!}{2!2!2!}$$

> 3) How many distinguishable arrangements of the letters of HULLABALOO contain the two letters HU next to eachother in that give order?

I joined HU into a single letter $\alpha$ and now I have the letters $\alpha$LLABALOO:

$$\frac{9!}{3!2!2!}$$

---

Are these correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are all correct - standard approaches to solving these types of problems.

Comment: Awesome. I hadn't heard of the second two methods, they just seemed to be valid approaches.

Comment: @Combinatorics Good for you! You did real mathematics, not just applying an algorithm by rote.

Comment: @DavidK Haha thank you, but this often makes it hard to check my answers. My newest question uses graph theory to solve a problem that was likely meant to be some simple combinatorial argument[which I am bad with at the moment ;)]