# How many different 4-letter arrangements can be made from the word GEOMETRY including at least one E?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So I stumbled upon a question: "How many different 4-letter arrangements can be made from the word GEOMETRY including at least one E?" How to solve such type of questions?

Comment: You might look at the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014457/arrangements-of-the-word-hullabaloo?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two possibilities: one letter E or two.

In the case of one E, there are $4$ possible positions for this first letter, and then 6 possibilities for filling the next letter (picking from the remaining letters, and excluding the other E), and then 5 possibilities, and then 4. So we have $4 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 480$.

In the case of two Es, there are $6$ possible positions for these first two letters. We can calculate this as ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ or just by intuitively observing that there are $4$ possibilities for the first E and then 3 for the second, but dividing by two since we don’t care about the order. Then $6$ more possibilities for the third letter, and then $5$. So we have $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 = 180$.

So our final total is $480 + 180 = 660$ possible arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

> We have '1105' matches. I found it by programming. My code is:

```
s = 'geometry'

m = []

for c1 in s:
    for c2 in s:
        for c3 in s:
            for c4 in s:
                m.append(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4)

filt = [eve for eve in m if eve.find('e') != -1]

print(len(set(filt)))
```

Comment: This code counts permutations with replacement, so it counts ‘EEEE’ as a possible arrangement, for example. It also counts ‘GEEM’ twice, for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Now I fixed the bug. Still we have a lot more than 660.

Comment: I believe you now have ‘E’ as one of your possible arrangements, as an example.

Comment: No, each arrangement must be of length 4 in my script. And I searched whole set of matches for 'e' match, didn't found it.

Comment: Each arrangement must be of length 4, but I think you still get ‘EEEE’ which then becomes ‘E’ when you convert your list to a set.

Comment: I commend you on trying to use a program to do this, but I don’t really think it’s the best way. For such a simple problem, I think direct calculation is easier and quicker. :)

Comment: Set ['eeee', 'eeee'] -> ['eeee'] not ['e']. Set will remove duplicates of matches, not chars within a match.

Comment: I was using ‘eeee’ as shorthand for [‘e’,’e’,’e’,’e’] in your program.

Comment: But my loop doesn't return match in ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e'] format. It returns match in 'eeee' format. Are you a programmer? Why you're doubtful? Didn't we found the truth? “Truth can only be found in one place: the code.” ― Robert C. Martin

Comment: But your program is still choosing *with* replacement... ‘gggg’ is a match. Do you think that should be the case? I had assumed that choosing *without* replacement was implicit in the question asked.

Comment: Look 'gggg' is not a match as per the question asked. Because it doesn't have an 'e'. So my script doesn't count 'gggg' as a match. So whats the problem. And i don't understand 'choosing without replacement'. Do you mean if 'ggge' is counted as a match, 'eggg' will not be counted as an another match; Because later have same chars as former but only shuffled?

Comment: Okay, you’re right, ‘gggg’ isn’t a match, but ‘ggge’ still is. Specifically, the 206th match in your set. Should it be?

Comment: I think we have different ideas of the problem to be solved. Your solution finds the number of permutations with replacement, whilst mine finds the number *without* replacement. I think the second is what is really being asked here. You can Google to find out what with or without replacement means.

Comment: Set is created in no order, elements each time ramdomly placed but 'ggge' is present in the set.

Comment: I have no great knowledge just like you, in this field, if you say I will just delete my answer.

Comment: No need to delete your answer. I just think that mine answers what is most likely the actual question—that’s all.

Comment: Since, questioner didn't added more info, mine answers too.